# PHP image save using curl giving garbage values

Tags: php, curl, garbage-collection

I am trying to save images using PHP code using cURL.

```
function scaleImageAndSaveIt($appName,$imageURL)
{
    $format=time();
    print_r($format);
    //$strf=strftime($format);
    $imageLocnName = $appName . "_" . $format ;
    $ch = curl_init($imageURL);
    print_r($imageURL);
    $fp = fopen($imageLocnName, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //exit;
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

when i am running this in browser it is giving garbage values on the screen and not saving the image also.

how do i save the image and what are those garbage values.

[IMAGE LINK](http://a4.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple1/v4/5d/03/0a/5d030a8a-a593-5eb7-9d2d-44c91de751a7/icon175x175.jpeg)

[image: Screenshot of the garbage values]

Comment: have you tried base64_decode your output string and check the output ?

Comment: That doesn't look like base64. Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` in the header to something like `image/png` or `image/jpg`? You can do this with PHP function `header()`.

Comment: ahhh...sorry to distrb people. there was problem with permissions to the folder.